# Example of use of std::forward_iterator

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a `compute` function that looks like this:

```
template <typename PayloadType, complex ValueType>
         static void comupte_everything(
         const typename std::vector<DataPointWithAverage<PayloadType, ValueType>>::iterator begin,
         const typename std::vector<DataPointWithAverage<PayloadType, ValueType>>::iterator end)
```

I want to extend that function so it can accept any iterators instead of just vectors, and I'm trying to do it with `std::forward_iterator`:

```
template <typename PayloadType, complex ValueType,
std::forward_iterator<DataPointWithAverage<PayloadType, ValueType>> Iterator>
         static void comupte_everything(
          const Iterator begin,
          const Iterator end)
```

Now, the compiler complains that I give forward_iterator too many arguments.

How do I use this correctly?

Comment: It's just `std::forward_iterator Iterator`.

Comment: So how do I limit it to the type that I want?

Comment: You need to separately check the return type with something like `requires std::same_as<std::iter_value_t<Iterator>, MyType>`.

Comment: "*So how do I limit it to the type that I want?*" What type do you want? If you're asking if it is an iterator over some particular type, then you should check that.

Comment: The question got extended from *"accepting any iterators"* to *"restricting `iter::value_type`"*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::forward_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator) is a concept, not a template, so you can't use it like a template, if you want to constrain the `value_type` of iterator, then you can

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_DataPointWithAverage = false;

template<typename PayloadType, complex ValueType>
constexpr bool is_DataPointWithAverage<
  DataPointWithAverage<PayloadType, ValueType>> = true;

template <std::forward_iterator I>
  requires is_DataPointWithAverage<std::iter_value_t<I>>
static void comupte_everything(I begin, I end);
```

which will constrain `I` must model `forward_iterator`, and its `value_type` must be a specialization of `DataPointWithAverage`.

Note that `begin()` and `end()` of a `range` in C++20 can return different types, so a more generic declaration should be

```
template <std::forward_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S>
  requires is_DataPointWithAverage<std::iter_value_t<I>>
static void comupte_everything(I begin, S end);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do we have a way to define a concept `my_forward_iterator` that also restricts `PayloadType` and `ValueType` so we can simply write `void compute(my_forward_iterator auto begin, my_forward_iterator auto end)`?

Comment: Something like `template<typename T> concept my_forward_iterator = forward_iterator<I> && is_DataPointWithAverage<iter_value_t<I>>;` But I don't recommend it since it doesn't well expressed in the function's signature.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an algorithm that iterates over a range of a specific type, defined by template parameters, then you should ask for that.

```
template typename PayloadType, complex ValueType, <std::forward_iterator It, std::sentinel_for<It> Sent>
    requires std::same_as<std::iter_value_t<It>, DataPointWithAverage<PayloadType, ValueType>>
  static void compute_everything(It start, Sent end)
{
}
```

Comment: `PayloadType, ValueType` seem to be non-deducible, so they should probably be first. Also could be an interesting idea to add `= It` as the default argument for `Sent`, to allow passing `{}` as sentiel (I'm thinking about `istream_iterator`, `directory_iterator`).

Comment: This is not right, you need to explicitly specify the `PayloadType` and `ValueType`, which will make you also need to explicitly specify the types of `It` and `Sent`. Even if you change the order of the template parameter,I don't think this way of invoking `comupte_everything<PayloadType, ValueType>(...)` is what the OP intended.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I fixed the parameter order.